# in python, find a line from file_A in file_B

Tags: python, search, match

Hello Python experts!!

Please see if there is a better way to do this.

I am trying to find a line in File-B for each line in File-A. The following code works for that purpose.

Q1: My problem is scaling. I have 2 files each with 50MM lines each. Can you please help come up with a better way at this scale.

Q2: Also, I need to find values from File-B that are in File-A(basically switching the files). I was planning to use the same script twice by switching the file names. Is there an efficient way to do this in one run?

```
fileA = open("file_a.txt","r")
linesOfA = fileA.readlines()

fileB = open("file_b.txt","r")

for lineB in fileB:
    if lineB in linesOfA:
        print "same",lineB
```

file_A:

```
123123123
123123456
123123789
```

file_B:

```
456456123
456456456
456456789
123123456
```

Result:

```
same 123123456
```

I'd really appreciate any help you can offer with this. 
Thank you

Comment: About Q2, you don't need to switch because the common part is always the same.

Comment: Koara, you are right. Thank you for bringing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that there is a unix utility called [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) (and a GNU-replacement, `calm`) that will do this job for sorted files.

You can sort your files (using `sort`) and then comm them. For example:

```
$ sort fileA.txt > fileA.sorted
$ sort fileB.txt > fileB.sorted
$ comm -12 fileA.sorted fileB.sorted > lines_in_both_files.txt
```

This is, obviously, not a Python solution. But you can expect significantly better performance than you are likely to get from Python for these sizes.

Comment: Thank you Austin! Though not in python, this does serve my purpose very very well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files only contain one number per line, one of the options would be to use sets:

```
a = set([1, 5, 6, 0])
b = set([0, 8, 2, 3, -5])
a.difference(b)   # returns: {1, 5, 6}
a.intersection(b) # returns {0}
b.difference(a)   # returns: {-5, 2, 3, 8}
```

From your code, I gather your computer can take it all in memory.
You are looking for the intersection case. And also, any value that file A has that is also in B, is also the same value that B has that is in A (that sounds weird to me, because it is so logical). It's because the intersection of two sets is the same for both.

All you would need to do is to use

```
a = set(linesOfA)
```

and similar for B.

Remark that this approach (using sets), will ignore all values that are double in one of the files. So if file A has twice the line "24" for example, your code will print 24 twice. With sets, you only see 24 once.

Comment: I might be able to get away to loading both the files into memory. 15bytes * 100MM rows, that amounts to about 1.5GB. Thanks for the suggestion.